# Plesk - SSH Terminal Extention - blank - broken connection

Tags: plesk, ssh

I installed the [SSH Terminal](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/ssh-terminal/) extention so that my customers can have access to SSH without giving them remote SSH access. When I (under admin or the customer) open up the SSH terminal, the terminal is blank and a "broken connection" error pops up. Now my remote SSH terminal (through putty) works just fine and so does my WinSCP (both using ssh),

I checked `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` tried enabling `"PermitRootLogin"` then restarting `sshd`, nothing changed not sure what else to check or try. Bear in mind that my remote ssh was working under root with that commented out.

System Information:

Server:
OS: CentOS 7

Plesk Version:
Plesk Obsidian Web Host Edition
Version 18.0.43 Update #1

Will update further if troubleshooting is requested or logs requested:

[image: Img]

Answer (score 4):

Found I was missing the following lines from the panel.ini file

```
[ext-ssh-terminal]
rootAccessAllowed = true
```

Immediately fixed the issue.